# Error in Keytool command

Tags: android, google-maps

hi when i try to run this command bin/keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android

i got the error java.lang.Exception Keystore file doesnot exist :debug.keyStore
 actually i am trying to get googlemaps key for android never used keytool command.

can any one help how to remove this error

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the keytool does not know where to look for the keystore file.
If you're on Windows 7 / Vista, try:

`keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore c:\users\your-user-name\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android`
(replace your-user-name with your actual user name)

For Windows XP, try:

`keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore c:\documents and settings\your-user-name\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android`

Comment: Did it help? If this is the solution, I suggest you mark it, so other users with find it too :-)

Answer (score 2):

If V2 map to generate SHA key use this command. use for releasing key means for testing.

```
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin>keytool.exe -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\DON\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android 
  Don is  usersystem name
```

If you want app live means for development.

```
   eclipse->Window ->Preferences ->Android ->Build -> now you get the sha key
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally i solve the problem and the correct working script / Command is below:
Please note the double quotes where they are placed please use as it is as this is the correct method. and off course please change the user name and as for the different versions of windows you people will have to change it accordingly. Please feel free to ask if you people have any questions.

> ```
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keys
> tore "c:\documents and settings\user\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android
>  -keypass android
> ```